# Moving Ofstream to class c'tor

Tags: c++, stream, ofstream

In main I have started an `ofstream` like this:

```
std::ofstream to(argv[2]);
```

Now I want to move it (not a copy) to my class builder like this:

```
class MyClass{
    std::ofstream output;
    MyClass(const std::ofstream &output=std::cout) output(output): {}
};
```

But that pops up many errors, any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of moving the `ostream` you should take a reference to it. Also, your class should contain a `ostream&` otherwise a default constructed `MyClass` will not work. Also, the constructor should take an `ostream&`, instead of `const ofstream&`, like this:

```
class MyClass{
    std::ostream &output;
  public:
    MyClass(std::ostream &output = std::cout) : output(output) {}
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sj9hzz).

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because you are trying to take a *copy* of the `ofstream`, but C++ streams are not copyable.

If you are using C++11 or later, you can use actual *move semantics*, eg

```cpp
class MyClass{
    std::ofstream output;
public:
    MyClass(std::ofstream &&output) : output(std::move(output)) {}
};

...

std::ofstream to(argv[2]);
MyClass cls(std::move(to));
```

Otherwise, use a non-owning reference or pointer instead (just make sure the stream outlives your class):

```cpp
class MyClass{
    std::ofstream &output;
public:
    MyClass(std::ofstream &output) : output(output) {}
};

...

std::ofstream to(argv[2]);
MyClass cls(to);
```

```cpp
class MyClass{
    std::ofstream *output;
public:
    MyClass(std::ofstream *output) : output(output) {}
};

...

std::ofstream to(argv[2]);
MyClass cls(&to);
```

Or, you could simply change your constructor to take a filename instead of a pre-existing stream:

```cpp
class MyClass{
    std::ofstream output;
public:
    MyClass(const char *filename) : output(filename) {}
};

...

MyClass cls(argv[2]);
```